# Hangfire - Prevent multiples of the same job being enqueued

Tags: c#, asp.net, hangfire

### Scenario:

**Job 1** is scheduled to run every 5 minutes, and takes ~1 minute to complete.

A lot of work piles up and **Job 1** takes 15 minutes to run.

There are now three **Job 1's** being processed concurrently - I don't want this.

---

How do I prevent **Job 1** being added to the queue again if it is already there?

Is there Hangfire setting, or do I need to poll job statuses manually?

Answer (score 21):

You can use [DisableConcurrentExecution](https://www.hangfire.io/blog/2014/05/21/hangfire-0.8.2-released.html#disableconcurrentexecution-filter) attribute to prevent multiple executions of a method concurrently. Just put this attribute above your method -

```
[DisableConcurrentExecution(timeoutInSeconds: 10 * 60)]
public void Job1()
{
    // Metohd body
}
```

Comment: someone report a bug about DisableConcurrentExecution attributes at 10 november 2016. Something could be wrong.

Comment: What if there are custom input parameters into Job1() method?

Comment: Note that Hangfire may cause database connection pool leaks this way: https://codewithstyle.info/real-bug-story-long-running-jobs-hangfire/

Comment: how to avoid throws timeout exception?

Answer (score 9):

Sounds like this could be something that you might be interested in:
https://discuss.hangfire.io/t/job-reentrancy-avoidance-proposal/607/8

The discussion is about skipping jobs that would be executed concurrently to a already running job.

Answer (score 9):

a bit late but i was using this class to prevent duplicate jobs to run concurrently

```
public class SkipConcurrentExecutionAttribute : JobFilterAttribute, IServerFilter, IElectStateFilter
{
    private readonly int _timeoutSeconds;
    private const string DistributedLock = "DistributedLock";

    public SkipConcurrentExecutionAttribute(int timeOutSeconds)
    {
        if (timeOutSeconds < 0) throw new ArgumentException("Timeout argument value should be greater that zero.");
        this._timeoutSeconds = timeOutSeconds;
    }

    public void OnPerformed(PerformedContext filterContext)
    {
        if (!filterContext.Items.ContainsKey(DistributedLock))
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Can not release a distributed lock: it was not acquired.");

        var distributedLock = (IDisposable)filterContext.Items[DistributedLock];
        distributedLock?.Dispose();
    }



    public void OnPerforming(PerformingContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.WriteLine("Job Started");

        var resource = String.Format(
                           "{0}.{1}",
                          filterContext.BackgroundJob.Job.Type.FullName,
                          filterContext.BackgroundJob.Job.Method.Name);

        var timeOut = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(_timeoutSeconds);

        filterContext.WriteLine($"Waiting for running jobs to complete. (timeout: { _timeoutSeconds })");

        try
        {
            var distributedLock = filterContext.Connection.AcquireDistributedLock(resource, timeOut);
            filterContext.Items[DistributedLock] = distributedLock;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            filterContext.WriteLine(ex);
            filterContext.WriteLine("Another job is already running, aborted.");
            filterContext.Canceled = true; 
        }

    }

    public void OnStateElection(ElectStateContext context)
    {
        //if (context.CandidateState as FailedState != null)
        //{

        //}
    }
}
```

Hope that helps, thx!

Comment: cancelling job doing the trick, yes. Also you could add method parameters to lock name and be able to run same method but with different arguments - each just once

Comment: Also, if you use job continuation, cancelling job will trigger job that depends on it as parent job was successed. Keep that in mind

Comment: To avoid that instead of filterContext.Canceled = true;  
throw new JobAbortedException(); 

this will tell worker to skip duplicate job run

Answer (score 7):

There is an attribute called DisableConcurrentExecution, that prevents 2 Jobs of the same type running concurrently.

Though, in your case it could be best, to check if a task runs and skip accordingly.

Comment: From my understanding this would prevent them from executing concurrently but they will still be queued to run. This is a step in the right direction but ideally they wouldn't be queued at all. 

Thanks for the answer!

Comment: That's what i meant with my second sentence. I don't think it is the right way to not queue the jobs, but let them start and check if a other job is currently running an then skip it right there...

Answer (score 6):

I solved this problem. I hope it works for you

```
public class PreventConcurrentExecutionJobFilter : JobFilterAttribute, IClientFilter, IServerFilter
{
    public void OnCreating(CreatingContext filterContext)
    {
        var jobs = JobStorage.Current.GetMonitoringApi().ProcessingJobs(0, 100);
        if (jobs.Count(x => x.Value.Job.Type == filterContext.Job.Type && string.Join(".", x.Value.Job.Args) == string.Join(".", filterContext.Job.Args)) > 0)
        {
            filterContext.Canceled = true;
        }
    }

    public void OnPerformed(PerformedContext filterContext) { }

    void IClientFilter.OnCreated(CreatedContext filterContext) { }

    void IServerFilter.OnPerforming(PerformingContext filterContext) { }
}
```

Usings:

1. Add to global filters

```
GlobalJobFilters.Filters.Add(new PreventConcurrentExecutionJobFilter());
```

2. or by Abstract base job class

```
[PreventConcurrentExecutionJobFilter]
public abstract class IHangfireJob { 

}
```

2. or by Single job

```
[PreventConcurrentExecutionJobFilter]
public class MyJob { 

}
```

Comment: Clean and nice, but there seems to be two issues here.
One that it does not check the method name, only type and arguments.
And one that there might be a race condition issue.
In recuring job I managed to get it in a state that two jobs where scheduled at the same time (recuring each second). Since none where in a running state, both started. If I moved the logic to OnPerforming, then both would be canceled.
If the same job is enqueued twice, it's simple to reproduce, not as simple in a recuring job.

Answer (score 3):

I was using the DisableConcurrentExecution attribute for my RecurringJob, but it was not working for me.

My mistake was that I was using it on my method and not on my interface.

```
[DisableConcurrentExecution(timeoutInSeconds: 10 * 60)]
Task SyncAllMyDataAsync();



RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<IMySyncJobs>("Sync my data", x => x.SyncAllMyDataAsync(), "0 0 * * * *");
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes.It is possible as below:

```
            RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(Environment.MachineName, () => MyJob(Environment.MachineName), Cron.HourInterval(2));
```

and MyJob should define like this:

```
    public void MyJob(string taskId)
    {
        if (!taskId.Equals(Environment.MachineName))
        {
            return;
        }
        //Do whatever you job should do.
    }
```

Comment: That doesn't solve OP's problem. Your answer only prevents a job to be executed in a machine other than the one where it has been queued, but it doesn't prevent reentrancy. In your example, if your job takes more than 2 hours to complete, then Hangfire would enqueue a new job, in the same machine, and you'd have two jobs of the same type, running at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i have many methods running in parallel, but i can't run the same method more than once.

Using a solution from this topic, I just edited the query. If was already one method in the processing list with the same name of the actual method,  the execution is cancelled.

I believe that resolve a lot of cases.

1. Create this class:

```
    using Hangfire.Client;
    using Hangfire.Common;
    using Hangfire.Server;
    using Hangfire;
    
    public class PreventConcurrentExecutionJobFilter : JobFilterAttribute, IClientFilter, IServerFilter
    {
        public void OnCreating(CreatingContext filterContext)
        {
            var jobs = JobStorage.Current.GetMonitoringApi().ProcessingJobs(0, 100);
    
            var methodAlreadyProcessing = jobs.Any(x => x.Value.Job.Method.Name == filterContext.Job.Method.Name);
    
            if (methodAlreadyProcessing)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now:HH:mm:ss} - Job {filterContext.Job.Method.Name} cancelled why was already exists in processing list!");
                filterContext.Canceled = true;
            }
        }
    
        public void OnPerformed(PerformedContext filterContext) { }
    
        void IClientFilter.OnCreated(CreatedContext filterContext) { }
    
        void IServerFilter.OnPerforming(PerformingContext filterContext) { }
    }
```

2. Put the Annotation in your method:

```
    [PreventConcurrentExecutionJobFilter]
    public async Task MyTopTask()
    {
      ...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class PreventConcurrentExecutionJobFilter : JobFilterAttribute, IClientFilter, IServerFilter
{    
    public void OnCreating(CreatingContext filterContext)
    {
        JobList<ProcessingJobDto> jobs = JobStorage.Current.GetMonitoringApi().ProcessingJobs(0, 100);
        if (jobs.Any(x =>
                        x.Value.Job.Type == filterContext.Job.Type &&
                        x.Value.Job.Method.Name == filterContext.Job.Method.Name &&
                        x.Value.Job.Args.Count == filterContext.Job.Args.Count &&
                        string.Join(",",x.Value.Job.Args) == string.Join(",", filterContext.Job.Args)))
        {
            filterContext.Canceled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

this filter check controller, method, parameter count and equality

Answer (score -4):

If you want to discard attempts to run something twice if it's already running you can always just do this (note no attributes applied):

```
    private static bool _isRunningUpdateOrders;
    public void UpdateOrders()
    {
        try
        {
            if (_isRunningUpdateOrders)
            {
                return; 
            }

            _isRunningUpdateOrders = true;

            // Logic...

        }
        finally 
        {
            _ isRunningUpdateOrders = false;
        }
   }
```

Edit: Please only use something like this as a quick fix, like if you've just discovered you have an issue and you're still evaluating better solutions :-) Or if you're lazy and you just want to 'sort of fix' the problem ;-)

Comment: bad answer. because you supposed that no one can call UpdateOrders, without lock? ok. you can use lock but again will be issue becasue you can not handle semafor.

Comment: @NuriYILMAZ this would only ever be called by hangfire. I realize this may not have been made clear. This should not be called by your ‘normal’ website. Call it Hangfire_Update orders or put it in a class HangfireTasks (that’s what I do).

Comment: @NuriYILMAZ what do you mean about semaphore?

Comment: This would fail when having multiple servers since statics will be server local.
If you only have a single hangfire instance it could work.

Comment: In order to avoid race conditions I would use `if (Interlocked.Exchange(ref _isRunningUpdateOrders, 1) == 1) return;` before the `try` statement and `Interlocked.Exchange(ref _isRunningUpdateOrders, 0);` inside the `finally` section. By the way, Hangfire documentation also mentions that sometimes people may instead prefer their own locking mechanism - in cases where there is single server processing the jobs.

Comment: This solution may even be the only possible solution since Hangfire may cause database connection pool leaks with alternative solution using the DisableConcurrentExecution attribute: https://codewithstyle.info/real-bug-story-long-running-jobs-hangfire/

Comment: This answer assumes there is only 1 server processing jobs.  This solution does not work across multiple servers.