# hangfire recurring job: prevent parallel execution of the same job

Tags: c#, .net, hangfire

I have implemented a recurring job which needs to run every minute. Now and then the job has a hickup as an API-Call is involved which can take a bit longer to response. So that the job is enqued a second time, even though it wasn't finished in the previous run.

My Question:
How do I prevent a Hangfire job to run if another instance of the same job is already running?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried this solution?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45164789/13206244

Comment: Seems to work. Thank you!