# Multi instance running for the same job in Hangfire

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, hangfire, .net-8.0

I have an asp.net core MVC 8 web app with hangfire (v1.8.7) configured that executes several jobs. Occasionally, a job may exceed the specified time and trigger another instance. My goal is to prevent Hangfire from launching multiple instances of the same job simultaneously.

> I have only one server running

I tried to use the DisableConcurrentExecution attribute but it didn't work

```
[DisableConcurrentExecution(timeoutInSeconds: (3600))]
public ActionResult SetScheduledJob_SyncModifiedItemsFromAffiliateBox()
{
    RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate("SyncModifiedItemsFromAffiliateBox_OffHours", () => 
        SyncModifiedItemsFromAffiliateBoxJob(), Cron.Minutely());

    return RedirectToAction("index");
}

public void SyncModifiedItemsFromAffiliateBoxJob()
{
    Thread.Sleep(2 * 60 * 1000);
}
```

this is my program.cs code:

```
// Add Hangfire services.
builder.Services.AddHangfire(configuration => configuration
    .SetDataCompatibilityLevel(CompatibilityLevel.Version_180)
    .UseSimpleAssemblyNameTypeSerializer()
    .UseRecommendedSerializerSettings()
    .UseSqlServerStorage(appSettings.GetConnectionString("HangfireConnection")));

// Add the processing server as IHostedService
builder.Services.AddHangfireServer();
```

```
app.UseHangfireDashboard();
app.MapHangfireDashboard();
```

Comment: Maybe this will solve your issue ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/74334104/20430576

Comment: Please be aware that when using DisableConcurrentExecution multiple instances of the same job will be reported to be in "Processing" state even though only one instance is actually running.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution that works for me:

- first, you need to create this class that gets registered jobs from the database and compares it with the ones running.
- create class PreventConcurrentExecutionJobFilter:

  public class PreventConcurrentExecutionJobFilter : JobFilterAttribute, IClientFilter, IServerFilter { }
- implements these methods on class:

  ```
    public void OnCreating(CreatingContext filterContext)
    {
        var jobs = JobStorage.Current.GetMonitoringApi().ProcessingJobs(0, 100);

        var methodAlreadyProcessing = jobs.Any(x => x.Value.Job.Method.Name == filterContext.Job.Method.Name);

        if (methodAlreadyProcessing)
        {
            filterContext.Canceled = true;
        }
    }

    public void OnPerformed(PerformedContext filterContext) { }

    void IClientFilter.OnCreated(CreatedContext filterContext) { }

    void IServerFilter.OnPerforming(PerformingContext filterContext) { }
  ```
- second you need to call this class as attributes for the job method:

  ```
    [PreventConcurrentExecutionJobFilter]
    public void SyncModifiedItemsFromAffiliateBoxJob()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(2 * 60 * 1000);
    }
  ```